# Parsing UI router states to URLs without Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I have a Angular 1.5.9 web application and a Node.js/Sails.js 0.12 backend.
Inside Angular runs UI router 0.4 to handle states.

The state definitions might look like this (quite vanilla, I'd say):

```
$stateProvider.state('dogs', {
            url: '/ourdogsarecute_{specialIDofDog}
        }).
        state('dogs.specialDogState', {
            url: '/specialinfo_{specialInfoOfDog}'
        });
```

Now, the following situation arises: **In the backend (i.e. outside of Angular)**, I have to transform an Angular UI router state link like
`{stateName: 'dogs.specialDogState', stateParams: {specialIDofDog: 11212, specialInfoOfDog: 'likesbones' } }` into a valid URL like `https://www.our-app.dog/ourdogsarecute_11212/specialinfo_likesbones`.

I have no idea how to do that without a lot of manual work. Is there a kind of parser for UI router states as a node module?

I can access the front-end code where the state definitions lie from the backend somehow. that's not the problem. The problem is the transformation from state links into URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI-Router 1.0 split the code up into ui-router core and ui-router angularjs.  You can use ui-router core (which has no external dependencies) on your node backend to generate these urls.  Since you already have your states available as a JSON file, you can simply register the states with ui-router core in your backend and then use the state objects to generate URLs.

In your node backend, add ui-router core

`npm install --save @uirouter/core`

```
// The library exports most of its code
var UIR = require('@uirouter/core');

// Create the router instance
var router = new UIR.UIRouter();
// Get the state registry
var registry = router.stateRegistry;

var states = [
  { name: 'dogs', url: '/ourdogsarecute_{specialIDofDog}' },
  { name: 'dogs.specialDogState', url: '/specialinfo_{specialInfoOfDog}' },
];

states.forEach(state => registry.register(state));

var params = { specialIDofDog: '11212', specialInfoOfDog: 'lovesbones' };

// Get the internal state object
var stateObj = registry.get('dogs.specialDogState').$$state();
// Generate the URL
console.log(stateObj.url.format(params));
```

Comment: Thanks! Works. However, I guess, you mean `npm install --save @uirouter/core`
instead of `npm add --save @uirouter/core`?

Answer (score 0):

For reference: my solution now looks like this.
First of all, I've put my state definitions into a separate file, making it easier to access it from outside:

```
var myStates = [
    {
        name: 'dogs', stateProperties: {
        url: '/ourdogsarecute_{specialIDofDog}'
    }
    }, {
        name: 'dogs.specialDogState', stateProperties: {
            url: '/specialinfo_{specialInfoOfDog}'
        }
    }];
```

And then in my app.config

```
for(var i = 0; i < myStates.length; i++) {
            $stateProvider.state(myStates[i].name, myStates[i].stateProperties);
        }
```

In the backend, I've created this function:

```
/**
   * @description Turns state name and state params into a URL string, using stateLinks definition synchronized from front end (being UI router state definitions)
   * @param {string}  stateName Something like 'dogs.info.specialAttributes'
   * @param {object}  stateParams Something like {dogID: 34346346, dogStatus: 'private', dogInfo: 'food'}
   * @returns {string} URL
   */
  stateLinkResolve: function(stateName, stateParams) {

    if(!(stateName && stateName.length > 0)) {
      return '/';
    }

    var resultUrl = '';

    var splittedSubStates = stateName.split('.');// split "dogs.info.specialAttributes" into ["dogs","info","specialAttributes"]

    var currentStateInHierarchy = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < splittedSubStates.length; i++) {

      /* Add dot if "in between": not the first, not the last. So that "dogs" remains "dogs", but when going to "dogs.info", we want the dot in between */
      if(i > 0 && i < (splittedSubStates.length + 1) ) {
        currentStateInHierarchy += '.';
      }
      currentStateInHierarchy += splittedSubStates[i]; // Add current splitted name (being only the last name part) to the state name in its context. I.e. when doing "info", we want to access "dogs.info"
      var currState = _.find(stateDefs,{name: currentStateInHierarchy});
      var urlRaw = currState.stateProperties.url;

      /* uiRouter URLs may contain wildcards for parameter values like /ourdogs_{dogID:int}_{dogStatus}/:dogInfo.
        We go through each of these three types and replace them with their actual content.
          */
      for(var currentParam in stateParams) {
        urlRaw = urlRaw.replace(':' + currentParam, stateParams[currentParam]); // search for ":paramName" in URL
        urlRaw = urlRaw.replace('{' + currentParam + '}', stateParams[currentParam]); // search for "{paramName}" in URL

        // search for "{paramName:paramType}" in URL
        var uiRouterParamTypes = ["hash", "string", "query", "path", "int", "bool", "date", "json", "any"];
        for(var j = 0; j < uiRouterParamTypes.length; j++) {
          urlRaw = urlRaw.replace('{' + currentParam + ':' + uiRouterParamTypes[j] + '}', stateParams[currentParam]);
        }
      }
      resultUrl += urlRaw;
    }
    return resultUrl;
  }
```

The problem is: This might fail for edge cases and it will definitely fail for new features being implemented to UI state router and the way URLs are built there. So, still hoping for a solution which directly uses UI router magic.